# access POST values for dynamically created text boxes in MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i created some text boxes dynamically using javascript, now i want to access them in my controller. I need a way to access the values in these text boxes in my controller action.

Comment: How did you created your textboxes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving them a 'name' attribute?

```
Request.Form["MyTextBox"]
```

Comment: thanks very much. i was initially giving them the id attribute instead of the name attribute so it wasn't showing up in the Request.Form collection.